# Solrcloud Zookeper Setup : No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: c1 slice: shard2

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

Am using solr 4.10.3, I start solr via embedded jetty server in java. Am trying to configure solrcloud with 2 shards(Leaders). I have an external zookeeper setup, I point to zookeeper instance while starting solr like this.

```
        System.setProperty("zkHost", "192.168.2.21:2111");
        System.setProperty("numShards", "2");
        System.setProperty("collection.configName", "configuration1");
        System.setProperty("bootstrap_confdir","/conf/zooconf");
```

I have two solr instances running, one in 8983 port & other in 8984. The problem is, am not sure whether both solr nodes are recognized as leader. Since i start solr via java, i cannot view the status in solr admin UI.

Following is my solr.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr>
  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">192.168.2.21</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${hostPort:8984}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${solr.zkclienttimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory" class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:120000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:15000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
</solr>
```

In main method i connect to one of the solr instances(8983) and create the core using the following code snippet.

```
    CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("192.168.2.21:2111"); 
    server.setZkConnectTimeout(15*60*1000);
    server.setZkClientTimeout(15*60*1000);
    server.setParser(new BinaryResponseParser());
    server.setRequestWriter(new BinaryRequestWriter());     
    server.setDefaultCollection("C1");

    Create adminRequest = new Create();
    adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.CREATE);
    adminRequest.setCoreName("C1");
    adminRequest.setCollection("C1");
    adminRequest.setCollectionConfigName("configuration1");
    adminRequest.setDataDir("c:\\setup\somelocation");
    adminRequest.setInstanceDir("c:\\setup\somelocation\C1");
    adminRequest.process(solrServer);
```

When i execute this, C1 is created in only one solr instance(8983). (**isn't the core supposed to be created in two solr instance's data directories.?**). And while adding the document, Following exception is thrown.

> No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: c1 slice: shard2

This is the clusterState while adding document :

```
live nodes:[192.168.2.21:8984_solr, 192.168.2.21:8983_solr] collections: {
   C1=DocCollection(C1)=   {
      "shards":{
         "shard1":{
            "range":"80000000-ffffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
               "core_node1":{
                  "state":"active",
                  "core":"C1",
                  "node_name":"192.168.2.21:8983_solr",
                  "base_url":"http://192.168.2.21:8983/solr",
                  "leader":"true"
               }
            }
         },
         "shard2":{
            "range":"0-7fffffff",
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{

            }
         }
      },
      "maxShardsPerNode":"1",
      "router":{
         "name":"compositeId"
      },
      "replicationFactor":"1",
      "autoAddReplicas":"false",
      "autoCreated":"true"
   }
}
```

And if i create the core in the other solr instance(8984) before adding the document, it works fine.. Documents are indexed and distributed between 2 shards. Is there anything wrong that i am doing? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following lines while creating the adminRequest, it worked

```
adminRequest.setPath("/admin/collections");
adminRequest.setNumShards(2);
```

Previously it dint work because default path was pointing to the old api "**/admin/cores**". We need make sure that new api path "**/admin/collections**" is given in adminRequest object for the solrcloud operations mentioned in [New Collection API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API).