# SOLR shards abruptly goes down

Tags: apache, hadoop, solr

I am processing around 7 billion documents per day into my solr cloud with 10 instances running with 5GB XMX and XMS values respectovely, which is getting pushed to one collection named 'X'. Its schema has around 150+ fields, out of which almost all of them are indexed. The collection X has 240 shards with 2 replication factor each.

The problem that I am facing currently is that, out of 240 shards, 3 to 4 shards randomly goes down with the following exception :

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: X slice: shard118
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:747)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.getLeaderRetry(ZkStateReader.java:733)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:305)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Followed by this we found another exception in the solr logs :

```
ERROR (zkCallback-4-thread-4-processing-n:<IP>:8983_solr) [c:X s:shard63 r:core_node57 x:X_shard63_replica1] o.a.s.c.Overseer Could not create Overseer node
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /overseer
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$9.execute(SolrZkClient.java:391)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$9.execute(SolrZkClient.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.create(SolrZkClient.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer.createOverseerNode(Overseer.java:731)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer.getStateUpdateQueue(Overseer.java:604)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer.getStateUpdateQueue(Overseer.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.ShardLeaderElectionContext.runLeaderProcess(ElectionContext.java:314)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.LeaderElector.runIamLeaderProcess(LeaderElector.java:170)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.LeaderElector.checkIfIamLeader(LeaderElector.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.LeaderElector.access$200(LeaderElector.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.LeaderElector$ElectionWatcher.process(LeaderElector.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$3.lambda$process$0(SolrZkClient.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As a solution, I deleted all the replicas and recreated them for the shards which were down. This solved the problem but it works intermittently.

Also this has a risk losing a good amount of data in case no in sync replicas are found.

Can anyone please suggest me a better way to resolve this issue. Also this is happening in production so I cannot recreate the collection ( which solves the problem but the same issue may re-appear again after some time ) nor can I afford to restart zookeeper as many other spark jobs are depenedent on the same.

I am stuck into this for long.

UPDATE :

We are not performing any operations on the SolrCloud due to which the shard may come down. The only operation that occurs is that a spark batch job runs on top of this collection, to process data. The spark batch job runs twice a day but shards do not come down during this period of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solrcloud Zookeper Setup : No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: c1 slice: shard2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515948/solrcloud-zookeper-setup-no-registered-leader-was-found-after-waiting-for-4000)

Comment: Unlike as mentioned in the stack above, there are no code level issue that has occurred here. The SolrCloud runs for a week and then abruptly the shards start coming down. There is no specific machine where it occurs .